# make python datetime include local time zone

Tags: python, datetime

I wrote this python code but I am facing problems to make it work properly at the level of time zone. So basically the datetime.now()  is not working as expected as it is not compliant to my local time (Paris local time) . Any idea how to sovle this please.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators import 
GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
copy_trm = GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id='copy_file',
        source_bucket="source",
        source_object="input-files/*.orc",
        destination_bucket="destination",
        destination_object="output-files/recent",
        last_modified_time=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
```

Best Regards

Comment: Looking at the airflow documentation, https://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=googlecloudstoragetogooglecloudstorageoperator I think `last_modified_time` is not expected to be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

use pytz module

```
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('Pacific/Johnston')   #change it to your suitable timezone
ct = datetime.now(tz=tz)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know your current timezone name. It is possible with below code:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
dt.astimezone().tzname()
```

Output:

```
'IST'
```

You can send time in UTC format as:

```
dt.astimezone().utcnow()
```

Answer (score 0):

### With the standard library, requires the numerical offset

If you have the numerical offset of your timezone (compared to UTC) then you use the standard library:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%c (%Z)")
'Wed Feb 13 23:00:06 2019 ()'
>>> datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).strftime("%c (%Z)")
'Wed Feb 13 22:00:11 2019 (UTC)'
>>> datetime.now(tz=timezone(timedelta(hours=2))).strftime("%c (%Z)")
'Thu Feb 14 00:00:20 2019 (UTC+02:00)'
```

Though since the offset can change throughout the year (e.g. with daylight saving time), it is recommended to use a named timezone.

### With `dateutils`, using the host timezones database

The [Python documentation on timezone](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) points to the [dateutil.tz](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html) package which will use the timezone database from the machine it runs on. The [pytz](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/) package on the other hand comes with a bundled timezone database.

I would personally recommend the `dateutil` package since the database already exists on the running machine. As long as the machine is kept up-to-date (as any server and PC should) you are good to go.

```
>>> from dateutil.tz import gettz  # GNU/Linux and macOS
>>> # Or, on Windows: from dateutil.tz.win import gettz
>>> datetime.now(tz=gettz("Europe/Paris")).strftime("%c (%Z)")
'Wed Feb 13 23:00:58 2019 (CET)'
>>> datetime.now(tz=gettz("Asia/Taipei")).strftime("%c (%Z)")
'Thu Feb 14 06:01:27 2019 (CST)'
```